# How to make sure specific view is visible when keyboard appears?

Tags: android

I have a layout with a graphic at the top, an `EditText` in the middle and a button some distance below it, like so:

[image: Example layout]

When the user is typing in the `EditText`, I want to pan the layout so that the "Go" button is still visible, even if that means clipping the image off the top, like so:

[image: Wanted layout]

I know about `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the manifest, but that doesn't work because it only pans far enough for the EditText to be visible. Is there a way to make sure it pans until the button is visible too?

---

For comments with K_Anas, this is my layout. It has all the extra margins and spacing removed compared to the first screenshot, to remove any other source of problems.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#999"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:hint="Sample..."/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Go"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spoke with the Android developers hangout, and it doesn't seem like there's an easy way to solve this problem. The consensus seems to be reworking the layout rather than having an API to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

did you tried:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

in your activity Tag in Manifest

see these [docs](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html) on android developer blog

I tried your layout with: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"`

and give me these results:

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's more what my plan B is. At the moment that wouldn't work since that's all in a RelativeLayout and not a ScrollView (I use `alignParentTop` and `alignParentBottom` and such like which don't work in a ScrollView), but I'll swap over to that if I have to.

Comment: Hi steve, you want that your graph always appear or what? because i have tried your layout with an edit text in center and button on the bottom of a relative layout and put like 300x150 dpixdpi imageview on top

Comment: Is the button visible as well? That's the hard part. Making just the EditText visible is easy, using the "adjustPan" setting.

Comment: Odd... that's definitely not working for me. Relative layout with alignParentTop, centerInParent and alignParentBottom, manifest with windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan". The EditText pans up ever so slightly, but the button is definitely covered by the keyboard. This is with Android v2.3 on a Samsung Galaxy S2, app compiled against v2.2. What are you testing one?

Comment: I have tested it on an Samsung Galaxy S embedded with 2.3.3, the app is target v 2.2 too

Comment: sorry adjustPan not working  i thought im using it but i was using adjustResize!! sorry for confusing you

Comment: adjustPan work without using ScrollView, you will get some problem in landscape, Perhaps you can design another layout for it

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Thanks for trying. I'll try once more for suggestions by asking the Android devs in their weekly Google+ hangout (in 1.5 hours) but if they don't have a better idea I'll redesign the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it isn't the BEST way, but couldn't you just change the layout attributes for your button (add/change a margin) and redraw when the edittext is clicked? Use an onClickListener & maybe invalidate your button.

Comment: Lol, that's very hacky - but it might work. However, before trying something like this I'd wrap everything in a ScrollView and try working with `adjustResize`; that would also be a pain, but would probably be easier.

Comment: (The reason it would be a pain is that 'alignParentBottom' becomes meaningless in a ScrollView, so I'd have to rework the whole layout to keep a footer view (not in the mockups above) always at the bottom of the screen. I'd also have to find a way to make sure the view prescrolled to the right point)